# Can't change directories in a docker container?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I am attempting to run a few commands inside of a docker container from it's host machine.  Typically when I want to execute a shell command in a docker container from the host I will do something like this:

```
docker exec -ti myContainer ls -l
```

which works fine.  But when I try to change directories like this:

```
docker exec -ti myContainer cd myDirectory
```

it throws the error:

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec:
>   \"cd\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 6):

`cd` isn't an OS executable, is a shell command. To run it, you'll need to run a shell to parse it. `docker exec -ti myContainer /bin/sh -c "cd myDirectory"`